# Join to later event

Tags: python, multithreading, process

Consider a Python script which spans multiple processes or threads (I have not decided which yet, I'm still experimenting). I would like to join all processes/threads spawned at a time later than when they are created. For that purpose I am using a list as a thread pool:

```
pool = []

for job in jobs:
    j = Process(target=some_Function, args=(some_Arg, ))
    j.start()
    pool.append(j)

# Lots of code

for p in pool:
    p.join()

do_Right_Before_Exiting()
sys.exit()
```

The problem with this approach is that there are many, many processes and the pool is acting like a memory leak. Eliminating the pool saves considerable memory, but I have no way to ensure that the processes finish. I could 'hack' a `sleep(30)` to give them time to complete, but I find this ugly and unreliable.

**How might I join a process / thread to a point other than where the code is run (maybe join to something like a C# label, or join to another event)?** Alternatively, how might I check that all processes / threads have completed and only then proceed?

Comment: Why not use a real thread/process pool?

Answer (score 0):

If an array of your threads takes up too much memory,  I think you have too many threads.  Try dividing the jobs into 8 threads only and see if that improves things.

Most people don't have more than 8 cores.

Comment: I know that it seems excessive, and in reality I am using a semaphore to only start so many threads at once. But that does not address the crux of the question: joining at a later time.

Comment: What does that mean and why do you want it?  I re-read your question and don't understand.